Why doesn't symfony 7 cookies not work, but vanilla php do?
In my little project I want a user to immediately log out if the user was banned (By Admin or by changing the Database with a tool). I tried to set a cookie with symfony but it doesn't work. But if I use vanilla PHP for this solution it works as requested.
For this I use an eventlistener named "UserStatusListener.php" and in my LoginController I have a function to handle the logout-message (The reason why the user was logged out).
Maybe one of you finds the issue. I want to use the Framework instead of vanilla PHP.
Here my EventListener:
<?php
// src/EventListener/UserStatusListener.php

namespace App\EventListener;

namespace App\EventListener;

use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\RequestEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Security;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class UserStatusListener
{
    private $userRepository;
    private $security;
    private $router;

    public function __construct(UserRepository $userRepository, Security $security, RouterInterface $router)
    {
        $this->userRepository = $userRepository;
        $this->security = $security;
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(RequestEvent $event): void
    {
        $user = $this->security->getUser();

        if ($user) {
            $updatedUser = $this->userRepository->find($user->getId());

            if ($updatedUser && $updatedUser->getBannedUntil() !== null) {
                $now = new \DateTime();
                if ($now < $updatedUser->getBannedUntil()) {
                    // Setze ein Cookie mit der Benutzer-ID
                    // $cookie = new Cookie('banned_user_id', $user->getId(), time() + 3600, '/', 'stage.hhb.kighlander.de', true); // 1 Stunde gültig
                    setcookie('banned_user_id', $user->getId(), time() + 3600, '/', '.kighlander.de', true);
                    // Erstelle eine neue Response, wenn keine vorhanden ist
                    if (!$event->getResponse()) {
                        $event->setResponse(new Response());
                    }

                    // Setze das Cookie in die Response-Header
                    // $event->getResponse()->headers->setCookie($cookie);
                    // Benutzer ausloggen und zur Logout-Methode weiterleiten
                    $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('app_logout')));
                    return; // Beende die Methode hier
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

And here my LoginController:
<?php
// src/Controller/LoginController.php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Attribute\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationUtils;

class LoginController extends AbstractController
{
    private $requestStack;
    private $userRepository;

    public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack, UserRepository $userRepository)
    {
        $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
        $this->userRepository = $userRepository;
    }

    #[Route('/login', name: 'app_login')]
    public function index(
        AuthenticationUtils $utils
    ): Response
    {
        $lastUsername = $utils->getLastUsername();
        $error = $utils->getLastAuthenticationError();

        return $this->render('login/index.html.twig', [
            'lastUsername' => $lastUsername,
            'error' => $error
        ]);
    }

    #[Route('/logout', name: 'app_logout')]
    public function logout()
    {

    }

    #[Route('/logout_message', name: 'app_logout_message')]
    public function logoutMessage(): Response
    {
        // $bannedUserId = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->cookies->get('banned_user_id');
        $bannedUserId = $_COOKIE['banned_user_id'] ?? null;
        if ($bannedUserId) {
            // Benutzer aus der Datenbank abrufen
            $user = $this->userRepository->find($bannedUserId);

            if ($user && $user->getBannedUntil() !== null) {
                $now = new \DateTime();
                if ($now < $user->getBannedUntil()) {
                    // Setze eine Warnung für den gebannten Benutzer
                    $this->addFlash('warning', 'Du bist gebannt. Bitte kontaktiere den Support.');
                }
            }

            // Lösche das Cookie
            $response = $this->redirectToRoute('app_micro_post');
            $response->headers->clearCookie('banned_user_id');
            return $response;
        } else {
            // Setze die Erfolgsnachricht für den normalen Logout
            $this->addFlash('success', 'Du hast Dich erfolgreich ausgeloggt.');
        }

        return $this->redirectToRoute('app_micro_post');
    }

}


At least a part of "service.yaml" for registration the EventListener
services:
  App\EventListener\UserStatusListener:
    tags:
      - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest }

I outcomment the framework-version and the implemented vanilla-version works.
Thank you ;)
To test the code I created a test-user, logged in (without a ban), change to phpmyadmin and set a ban_until one day in future, change to the logged in user, make a click to another part of the app and I was logged out with the "normal" logout-message.
After I made the changes to vanilla php I got the correct logout message "Du bist gebannt. Bitte kontaktiere den Support" (Sorry, my site is in german ;) )
